# is it faster to read 100 lines of 50 characters each one from mysql or to read them from a text file?

Tags: php, mysql

If I would like to read using php, `100 lines`, which is faster? Reading them from `MySql table` or from a simple `Text File`?

Comment: Depends on many things. How would they be placed in a mysql table? Will these entries be static? How do these lines look? You need to provide a little more detail.

Comment: Depends on a number of factors.  Is the 100 lines in the text file the *only* thing in the text file or do you have to scan for it.  Is the mysql server local or on another machine, can you get to the data in mysql with a proper index so finding it is fast?  Try it out and see what your results are.

Comment: Your talking 5K characters. Why are your worried about speed?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123947/speed-mysql-vs-file-output

Comment: also depends how your script takes exactly 100 lines from a file =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use whatever suits you better.

For 100 lines, and a read-everything-at-once operation, the performance difference is going to be so minuscule it won't matter at all.

Comment: A text file may be less hassle than a database maintenance-wise - for example, you can move the script easily without having to export and import a database dump.

Answer (score 2):

Try it out:

```
$time_start = microtime();
$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT 100");
$time_end = microtime();
echo 'TIME: '.($time_end-$time_start).'<br>';

$time_start = microtime();
$fh = fopen("file.txt",'r');
$x=0;
while(($row = fgets($fh, 4096)) !== false) {
    if($x>100){
        break;
    }
    $x++;
}
fclose($fh);
$time_end = microtime();
echo 'TIME: '.($time_end-$time_start).'<br>';
```

It would seem to me that locating a file on the server, opening, running, & closing would be slower than having an active database connection. But, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Go for MySQL. IT would be very faster when you compare it with reading from a text file.

Comment: Alright i'll take your advice into consideration. I will test my code and then will get back here with the boring details ! :)

Answer (score 0):

If the file contains only 100 lines (so you basically read it from the beginning to the end) and you don't have to filter it somehow, then reading from file is faster.

MySQL reads from files as well (something is also cached in RAM).

Since you mentioned MySQL I suspect it isn't that simple. If it isn't just go for MySQL and you'll be happy ;)

Answer (score 0):

like another said, the difference should be minuscule.  if you really need the fastest possible access time, MySQL HEAP (memory) tables should return much faster than file access.